# Service Worker не ловит запросы до первого обновления страницы

Tags: javascript

https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/demos/manual-response/
Нашел этот пример, в нем можно посмотреть эту проблему:

Я открываю DevTools, если поставить breakpoint в SW addEventListener('fetch') и ввести в консоле fetch('/'), то ничего не произойдет, но если обновить страницу и сделать тоже самое, то справа от breakpoint появится синяя полоска, то есть, событие будет поймано.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы SW отлавливал события до первого обновления?
Браузер: Chrome

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, который бы воспроизводил проблему.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а что у Вас не получилось воспроизвести?

Comment: Проблему воспроизвести получилось. Но, по правилам **stackoverflow**, да и вообще, по хорошему, вопрос должен содержать **пример кода**, который бы воспроизводил проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте в обработчики события **install** добавить следующий код  `self.skipWaiting();`. Взято с https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-03